# How to compare distribution of proportions in two variables?

Tags: hypothesis-testing

[image]

This is the table I have. 
Four characteristics are mutually exclusive. A and B are two groups. I would like to know whether distribution of characteristics in A is different than that in B. What statistical test I can apply?

Comment: Do you have multiple independent measurements of the four characteristics inside of each group ? Or only this table of 2*4 values ?

Comment: @Rodolphe Characteristic 1 and every other characteristic is made up of several other measures. But I want to compare these two columns as seen in the table.

Comment: Do you have access to the individual measures ?